What is the name of this film about a military person living on an island?
I saw a film (maybe from Italy) on TV, but not all of it and I don’t know the name of the film or the actors & creator. 
Here is the part of the story that I saw: 
A military person lives on an island and reports with a radio to planes that go above it. By an accident, the trooper helps a woman teacher with her girl students and carries them with a boat to his place. He contacts his leaders with the radio and they say he must stay for a few days until they can move the woman and her students. The girls are children of ambassadors. He lives in a hut on the island and the teacher forces him to leave the hut and go to a beach where there is a big boat at the sea side. They clean the hut and the teacher hide his alcohol because she thinks the trooper drinks too much. After a few days he teaches the teacher how to get fish by hand. When the teacher goes out with some students, she trips and scratches her foot scratch with a tree limb and they think a snake has bitten the teacher. When they tell the trooper, he ask over the radio about the snake of this region from leaders. They tell him it has strong poison and he must give her any tranquilizer therefore he gives her the alcohol.
I saw only this part of the film. Can you recognize it?

It sounds like Father Goose (1964).
Starring Cary Grant and Leslie Caron. Wikipedia, IMDb
Some relevant points:
Cary Grant's character is a drunken beachcomber on deserted Matalava Island, employed by the military to watch for Japanese planes.
Leslie Caron's character is a schoolteacher with 7 pupils who is evacuated to the island.
She gets bitten by a snake.
